# How to view logs ,that are being shown in flutter debug console, inside the app being developed?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, logging, logcat

I would like to create a screen in my android/iOS app where anyone can see the messages that were thrown by dart runtime. I simply want to show Everything that is being shown in the debug console of VsCode or AndroidStudio, inside my android or iOS app in a dedicated screen. Every where I search I have found only information on how to add/create custom logs. while this is very useful I would also like to see messages or error shown in debug console to be seen on my app.

I know about flutter logs terminal command which can show all the logs being generated when the app is running. My question then is how can I listen or subscribe to these logs and show them inside my app such that I can get people to test my app and they can simply share their screen shots of the log screen inside app and share it to me OR or share it as text file to me.

I am open to any suggestions on a better way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: simply i want show to every message that appear in the debug console on a screen in my app.